# How to do treat octal numbers as decimal when doing arithmetics under busybox' ash

Tags: linux, shell, busybox, openwrt, ash

I have decimal numbers stored in strings.

The numbers which are < 100 are stored in this way `"045"` or `"005"`.

When using these number strings in arithmetic operations like `let A="045"+"009"` these numbers are treated as octal numbers like indicated in the man page.

To treat them as decimal I added `10#` at the beginning of the number strings like that

```
let A="10#045"+"10#123"
```

but this solution causes an error `-ash: let: arithmetic syntax error` in my bash from BusyBox (Installed on OpenWRT)

Is there another solution for my busybox shell?

**Note**: The operation should evaluated with `let` because I need theses numbers in other kind of operations like bitwise operation.

Comment: Can you use `expr` instead?

Comment: @MichaelGardner I want to use bitwise also operation on theses numbers. And expr does not support bitwise operation

Answer (score 4):

`busybox` does not have `bash`, its shell is `ash`.

You can either strip the leading zeros off your variables, e.g.:

```
while [ "${n:0:1}" = "0" ]; do n="${n#?}"; done
```

or use `expr`:

```
$ echo $(expr 045 + 045)
90
```

Comment: There is no `let` in my answer. Use `expr` instead of `let`.

Comment: e.g.: `A="$(expr 045 + 045)"`

Comment: expr does not support bitwise operations

Comment: No, but your question was how to simply add two numbers. If your goal is something else, you have to be more specific in your question. Also, you can break up your calculation to use both.

Comment: You didn't ask about Bitwise, you asked about decimal arithmetic.

Comment: Any way I want to use these number in the let and not in the exp

Comment: If `ash` does not support it, it does not support it. If you really want to *only* use `expr` I suggested getting rid of the leading zeros as a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I m gonna to replace the 0 in the beginning of the string number by space to avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the zeros before doing the arithmetics:

```
n=005
shopt -s extglob
n1=${n##+(0)}
echo $n1
```

Output:

```
5
```